# app_id and app_code in HTML and JavaScript

Tags: here-api

I found the same questions in the past. But there were no clear answers, and maybe since then something was changed. In the examples for javascript, app_id and app_code are written in the HTML / javascript code. Should the developer use some techniques to hide or secure app_id and app_code?

Answer (score 0):

In your HERE dashboard, you can set the application id and application code to only work on a particular domain or set of domains. If the tokens are fixed to a domain, it won't matter if someone takes your tokens because only the listed domains can use them. If you don't secure the tokens to a domain, then someone will be able to use your tokens if they find them.

Does that help?

Comment: If I want to use the javascript code in the HTML page to show here-map to anyone who opens my website, how can I know a domain of somebody who opens the website?

Comment: The domain is not of each of your users, but the website address. So if you're using HERE on a website example.com, then you'd include example.com in the list of domains in the HERE dashboard.